# Abstract class for classes with different types of parameters

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to C# and I believe similar question has been answered already, but am not sure what to search for, so here is the question:

I have two classes that have some identical methods and constructors. However, these methods and constructors accept different types of parameters (the Dictionaries variables are different). So how do I put these methods and constructors into abstract class `Brain`?

**Brain.cs**

```
public abstract class Brain
{
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
}
```

**Reward.cs**

```
public class Reward:Brain
{

    public Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, int> r = 
              new Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, int>();
    public Reward(int w, int h)
    {
        int directionsCount = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Direction)).Length;
        int direction;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                for (direction = 0; direction < directionsCount; direction++)
                {
                    Point state = new Point(i, j);
                    r[Tuple.Create(state, (Direction)direction)] = 0;
                }
    }
    public void Set(Point state, Direction direction, int reward)
    {
        r[Tuple.Create(state, direction)] = reward;
    }
    public int Get(Point state, Direction direction)
    {
        return r[Tuple.Create(state, direction)];
    }       
}
```

**Quantity.cs**

```
public class Quantity:Brain
{   
    public Quantity(int w, int h)
    {
         .........
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                for (direction = 0; direction < directionsCount; direction++)
                {
                    Point state = new Point(i, j);
                    Set(state, (Direction)direction, 0);
                }
    }
    private Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, decimal> q =
            new Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, decimal>();         
         .....
    public decimal Get(Point state, Direction action)
    {
        return q[Tuple.Create(state, action)];
    }
    public void Set(Point state, Direction action, decimal value)
    {
        q[Tuple.Create(state, action)] = value;
    }           
}
```

Comment: By using a generic abstract class as `Brain<T>`. Now your classes derive from that class by using `Quantity : Brain<MyType>`.

Comment: I suppose you know you can write integer as decimal, because this is the only one different type which I see.

Comment: Usually, it would be better to have a `Brain<T>` object as a member of `Reward` and `Quantity` classes. Inheritance should only be used for IS-A relationship.

Comment: Your code for enumerating `Direction` values is really fragile. It assumes that values start at 0 and are in increasing order without any hole. You should really use `GetValues` instead and also use a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define Brain as Generic class  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sz6zd40f.aspx) :

```
public abstract class Brain<T>
 {
     protected int width;
     protected int height;
     public Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, T> r = 
                 new Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, T>();
     public void Set(Point state, Direction direction, T reward)
     {
         r[Tuple.Create(state, direction)] = reward;
     }
     public T Get(Point state, Direction direction)
     {
         return r[Tuple.Create(state, direction)];
     }
 }
```

And than you could define your classes as:

```
public class Reward : Brain<int>
{
}

public class Quantity : Brain<decimal>
{
}
```

You could perhaps redefine `Reward` and `Quantity` methods as only one method in base class, they do look very likely, but i don't know, what is happenning in the code you hide behind "..."

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using generics:

```
public abstract class Brain<TValue> // TValue is the generic type parameter
{
    protected int width;
    protected int height;

    // use TValue in the declarations
    public Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, TValue> r = new Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, TValue>();
    public abstract void Set(Point state, Direction direction, TValue reward);
    public abstract TValue Get(Point state, Direction direction);
}
```

And declare the derived classes like this:

```
public class Reward : Brain<int> // int is now the generic type argument
{
    public override void Set(Point state, Direction direction, int reward)
    {
        r[Tuple.Create(state, direction)] = reward;
    }
    public int Get(Point state, Direction direction)
    {
        return r[Tuple.Create(state, direction)];
    }
}

public class Quantity : Brain<decimal>
{ ... }
```

---

But this has the disadvantage that `Brain<int>` and `Brain<decimal>` are totally different *invariant* types. So you could not assign an instance of `Reward` and an instance of `Quantitiy` to the same variable of type `Brain<sometype>`:

```
Brain<int> brain = new Reward(0, 0); // works
brain = new Quantitiy(0,0); // fails because Quantity is not a Brain<int>
```

So if you only want to inherit functionality or declarations, the generic approach is fine. But if you for example want to keep `Reward`s and `Quantity` instances together in a `List<Brain<T>>` this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would consider alternatives to your design.

Inheritance should not be used for code reuse purpose but for [Is-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship. It would be preferable to use composition instead: [Inheritance (IS-A) vs. Composition (HAS-A) Relationship](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php).

```
public class Brain<T>
{
    private readonly int width;
    private readonly int height;
    private readonly Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, T> r;

    Brain(int width, int height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        .........
        r = new Dictionary<Tuple<Point, Direction>, T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                foreach (Direction direction in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction))
                {
                    var state = new Point(i, j);
                    Set(state, direction, default(T));
                }            
    }

    public void Set(Point state, Direction direction, T reward)
    {
        r[Tuple.Create(state, direction)] = reward;
    }

    public T Get(Point state, Direction direction)
    {
        return r[Tuple.Create(state, direction)];
    }
}
```

Then other classes would use composition. For example, for the `Reward` class:

```
public class Reward
{
    Reward(int width, int height)
    {
        rewards = new Brain<int>(width, height);

        // Somehow initialize actual rewards here...
        rewards.Set(new Point(5, 8), Direction.Up, 10); // fictif example
    }

    private readonly Brain<int> rewards;
}
```

Thus the `Brain` class would essentially manage information for each position.

Then, I might consider if it really worth to have multiple types. Maybe rewards could also be a `decimal` afterwards particularly if they are multiplied at some point by the quantity which is already `decimal`.

However, even better might be to have a class that represent all information about a given position and direction:

```
public class PositionInfo
{
    public PositionInfo(int reward, decimal quantity)
    {
        Reward = reward;
        Quantity = quantity.
    }

    public int Reward { get; }    // C# 6 - Read-only properties.
    public decimal Quantity { get; }
}
```

If many of the items use default values and the dimension are larges, you might consider using `TryGetValue` and only fill information for position/direction that are not using the default values. Then modify `Get` to return default information when item is not in the dictionary. In fact, if all positions are filled, then using a multi-dimensional array might be a better option.

I would also add validation like `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert` to help find bugs during development.